# React with TypeScript Project contains JS written file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If React with Typescript project contains few JS components, does it make a problem while building in production?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't because the typescript files get rewritten to javascript by the compiler and it doesn't make a difference